# Facebook SDK Login doesn't work on simulator on iOS 10, Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, facebook-login

I try to login via the Facebook SDK login system in `viewWillAppear` like so:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if !loggedIn {
        if let token = FBSDKAccessToken.current() {
            loggedIn = true
            self.accessToken = token
        } else {
            let login = FBSDKLoginButton()
            login.center = view.center
            view.addSubview(login)
        }
    }
}
```

This **does** work properly on a real device, but lately on the iOS 10 simulator, using Xcode 8 and Swift 3 it seems to fail. The login button works normally and prompts to login and authorization page, but after authorizing/logging in, the token (`FBSDKAccessToken.current()`) remains `nil`.
Again, the problem only applies on the simulator, using iOS 10, Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

What could be the problem and how can I get this to work on the simulator? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you add keychain sharing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If its working fine on a real device, this means that you have successfully integrated the **Facebook SDK**. In order to make things working on iOS 10 simulator :
Go to the `Project Target` and then `Capabilities` and switch **Keychain Sharing** **ON**. 
 
It will ask for a Team for the first time. Select a team and it will add a Keychain Group for you.

[image]

Comment: This was the crucial piece of information missing everywhere. Seems like FB developers don't use iOS simulators, since their documentation is always half-baked.

Comment: Thanks..!! you help me a lot, this even work for ionic Facebook login part..!!